# Docker run github branch/pull request

Tags: docker

I forked `whilp/ssh-agent` and created a feature enhancement and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/whilp/ssh-agent/pull/3).

I want to reference/use my branch until it is accepted. On my CI agents, and I don't want to go locally to each one to build a local image.

[github.com/rosskevin/ssh-agent branch: feature-known-hosts](https://github.com/rosskevin/ssh-agent/tree/feature-known-hosts) is what I'd like to use with the `run` command, is this possible? I can't find references to using github (not to mention a branch) with `run`, only build.

i.e.

```
docker run -d --name=ssh-agent whilp/ssh-agent \
   github.com/rosskevin/ssh-agent -b feature-known-hosts
```

Any other advice on docker project patches/workflow/best practices?  This is really easy with Bundler, looking for an analog here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a docker image directly from GitHub, because GitHub is made to store only the code itself.

When you run the following command:

```
docker run -d --name=ssh-agent whilp/ssh-agent
```

Docker is looking for `whilp/ssh-agent` on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/), and not on GitHub.
Docker Hub is the equivalent of GitHub for Docker images.

To use your pull request the same way you are using `whilp/ssh-agent`, you need to create an account on Docker Hub, and create an automated build based on your `ssh-agent` fork ([tutorial here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/)).

Finally, you will be able to use your version with:

```
docker run -d --name=ssh-agent <username>/ssh-agent
```